# Fill Pandas column based on column value to column name — loc assignment not working in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

With data in this format

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'fill_value_col': [0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
   'col_0': [34.2, 53.3, 78.2, 53.1, 54.1],
   'col_1': [65.2, 65.1, 12.3, 79.3, 31.3],
   'col_2': [11.2, 58.3, 12.9, 53.2, 35.9]
})
```

I need to refill `fill_value_col` with the value that is in the same row in the column corresponding to the value in that row in `fill_value_col`. So for example, since there's a `1` in the second row of `fill_value_col`, there would need to be `65.1` where `1` is currently. The output should look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'fill_value_col': [34.2, 65.1, 78.2, 53.1, 35.9],
   'col_0': [34.2, 53.3, 78.2, 53.1, 54.1],
   'col_1': [65.2, 65.1, 12.3, 79.3, 31.3],
   'col_2': [11.2, 58.3, 12.9, 53.2, 35.9]
})
```

At the moment I'm trying to do `.loc` assignment in a for loop, which for some reason is only working in some rows:

```
for i in list(range(3)):
    df.loc[
        df.fill_value_col==i,
        'fill_value_col'
    ] = df.loc[
            df.fill_value_col==i,
            'col_'+str(i)
        ].copy()
```

I'm trying to figure out why this method isn't working and what an alternative method would be.

Edit: Changed my example code to reflect what I'm actually using (unintentional error in translating it from my local context to this MERV).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a numpy version of indexing after adding the prefix to the `fill_value_column`

```
prefix='col_'
df['fill_value_col_new'] = df.to_numpy()[df.index,
              df.columns.get_indexer(df['fill_value_col'].astype(str).radd(prefix))]
```

---

```
print(df)

   fill_value_col  col_0  col_1  col_2  fill_value_col_new
0               0   34.2   65.2   11.2                34.2
1               1   53.3   65.1   58.3                65.1
2               0   78.2   12.3   12.9                78.2
3               0   53.1   79.3   53.2                53.1
4               2   54.1   31.3   35.9                35.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `pd.factorize()`

```
idx,cols = pd.factorize(df['fill_value_col'].map('col_{}'.format))

df.assign(fill_value_col = df.reindex(cols,axis=1).to_numpy()[range(len(df)),idx])
```

Original Answer:

Here is a way to get around using the depreciated `lookup` function.

```
i = df.set_index('fill_value_col',append=True).index
df.assign(fill_value_col_new = df.loc[:,'col_0':'col_2'].rename(lambda x: int(x[-1]),axis=1).stack().loc[i].tolist())
```

Output:

```
   fill_value_col  col_0  col_1  col_2
0            34.2   34.2   65.2   11.2
1            65.1   53.3   65.1   58.3
2            78.2   78.2   12.3   12.9
3            53.1   53.1   79.3   53.2
4            35.9   54.1   31.3   35.9
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for i in list(range(3)):
df.loc[
    df.fill_value_col==i,
    'fill_value_col'
] = df.loc[
        df.fill_value_col==i,
        'col_'+str(i)
    ]
```

will result in:

```
fill_value_col  col_0  col_1  col_2
0            34.2   34.2   65.2   11.2
1            65.1   53.3   65.1   58.3
2            78.2   78.2   12.3   12.9
3            53.1   53.1   79.3   53.2
4            35.9   54.1   31.3   35.9
```

the reason why your solution didn't work as expected was because you have set the wrong target column to overwrite in your `.loc` statement. I hope this helps you to understand your bug, anyway i think a solution without for loop would be more convenient

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! The correct version of my original code that you give here is actually the version that's not working consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Check `lookup`

```
df['new'] = df.lookup(df.index,df.fill_value_col.astype('str').radd('col_'))
```